# Square brackets breaking OAuth signature generation - how to encode them?

Tags: ruby, oauth, openssl

I'm generating an OAuth signature using Ruby, for a site that uses OAuth.  It's been working fine up till now, till I've tried to add some params with square brackets.  Now I'm getting a "Signature doesn't match" error back.

My guess is that when Oauth generates the signature, it deals with the square brackets in a different way to how I deal with them when I generate my signature.

This is how I'm generating my OAuth sig (in Ruby):

```
oauth_params = {
  "oauth_consumer_key" => options["key"], #oAuth Consumer Key
  "oauth_nonce" => MiscUtilities.generate_nonce, #oAuth Nonce - just a random numnber
  "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1", #oAuth Signature Method - don't need to change this
  "oauth_timestamp" => Time.now.to_i.to_s, #oAuth Timestamp, standard seconds since epoch.
  "oauth_version" => "1.0" #oAuth Version - don't need to change this
}
#add any other non-oauth params we've been given
params = oauth_params.merge(options["params"])

#sort and url encode the params
encoded_params = params.sort_by{|k,v| k.to_s}.collect { |k, v| CGI.escape("#{k.to_s}=#{v}") }.join('%26')
signature_base_string = "#{options["method"]}&#{CGI.escape(options["api_url"])}&#{encoded_params}"
signing_key = "#{options["secret"]}&" 

#generate the signature and add it to params
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, signing_key, signature_base_string)
params["oauth_signature"] = Base64.encode64(hmac).chomp
params
```

Like I say, this was working fine till I added square brackets to the mix.

Has anyone encountered this problem, or able to see what I might be doing wrong, above?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "square brackets"? Are you talking about calling your options hash, as in `options["secret"]`? Also, is the trailing `&` at end of `signing_key` on purpose? And are your options for `method` and `api_url` supposed to be key/value pairs? (e.g. `method=#{option["method"]}&`)

Comment: Hi @JayDorsey.  For "square brackets" i meant a parameter like `student[id]=123` or `ids[]=4561&ids[]=678`.  I actually figured this out, I'm going to write it up into an answer later.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using CGI:Escape on a URL nor on the whole key value pair.  It should be used on the key, and separately on the value.  Then these two would be joined by an equal sign, and then these pairs would be added to the query string separated by &'s.

Speaking of which -- I see that you are joining with '%26' (encoded &).  This doesn't seem to follow the spec, unless perhaps your base values don't need encoding?  That would be equivalent to 'encoding' the values, and then encoding the whole string. And perhaps that's why the brackets caused an issue -- as soon as you added them to a value, that value then needed to be encoded.

```
 encoded_params = Map [params.map {|k, v| CGI.Escape(k), CGI.Escape(v)}]
                  .sort_by{|k,v| k.to_s}
                  .collect { |k, v| CGI.escape("#{k.to_s}=#{v}") }
                  .join('%26')
```

I'm not a ruby guy -- I just took an example from an answer on processing a hash and applied it here.  Please do what needs to be done to make this correct ruby code.  I also kept the rest of the code; while potentially confusing, it seems like it would do the job.

There is another potential issue -- According to the spec, the URI encoding that's done may be a little different than a normal URI encoding.  Spaces are %20 and not +, and everything but ALPHA, DIGIT, '_', '-', '.', and '~' Must be encoded, and those values must not be encoded.  So does that apply to CGI:Escape?  I don't have ruby installed, and my quick check on the spec lead me to a one line document.

edit: the algorithm above wouldn't work with things that need to be encoded, because the %'s from the things that are encoded would *also* be encoded.  It just needs a slight tweak to encode the entire value instead of joining with the encoded ampersands.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up doing all the things you suggest above, I think, perhaps in a different way - see my answer below(above?).  The space did have to be encoded as a %20, which i handle specifically, and yes there's a set of characters that we don't want to encode.  It seems quite fiddly.

Comment: @Max, agreed that it seems fiddly -- probably because the spec talks in generalities, and then makes exceptions, instead of describing what is needed in a progressive fashion.

Comment: Yeah while I was reading that spec I kept thinking "There's got to be a cleaner way to describe this". That's v1 though, maybe v2 is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is you have to convert the square brackets in the signature base string twice:

- [ => %5B =>  %255B
- ] => %5D =>  %255D

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, which I don't think is particularly clean but does work.

```
#New version following https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html
def oauth_signed_params(options)
  #defaults
  options["method"] ||= "POST"

  oauth_params = {
    "oauth_consumer_key" => options["key"], #oAuth Consumer Key
    "oauth_nonce" => generate_nonce, #oAuth Nonce - just a random number
    "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1", #oAuth Signature Method - don't need to change this
    "oauth_timestamp" => Time.now.to_i.to_s, #oAuth Timestamp, standard seconds since epoch.
    "oauth_version" => "1.0" #oAuth Version - don't need to change this
  }
  params = oauth_params.merge(options["params"])
  encoded_params = params.sort_by{|k,v| oauth_percent_encode(k.to_s)}.collect{|k, v| "#{oauth_percent_encode(k.to_s)}=#{oauth_percent_encode(v.to_s)}" }.join('&')

  signature_base_string = "#{options["method"]}&#{oauth_percent_encode(options["api_url"])}&#{oauth_percent_encode(encoded_params)}"
  signing_key = "#{options["secret"]}&" 

  #generate the signature and add it to params
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
  hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, signing_key, signature_base_string)
  params["oauth_signature"] = Base64.encode64(hmac).chomp
  params     
end

#according to this twitter oauth doc, we actually only percent-encode a limited set of characters.  
#Others are left as is. The ones in the regex below are NOT encoded.
#https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html
def oauth_percent_encode(string)
  string.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_\~]/){|match| match == " " ? "%20" : CGI.escape(match)}
end
```